# How do I convert a __CUDACC_VER__ value into a MAJOR, MINOR, BUILD triplet?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

When a newer (CUDA 9) version of nvcc encounters `__CUDACC_VER__`, it gives up and tells you something like:

```
/usr/local/cuda/include/crt/common_functions.h:64:24: error: token ""__CUDACC_VER__ is no longer supported.  Use __CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__, __CUDACC_VER_MINOR__, and __CUDACC_VER_BUILD__ instead."" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
 #define __CUDACC_VER__ "__CUDACC_VER__ is no longer supported.  Use __CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__, __CUDACC_VER_MINOR__, and __CUDACC_VER_BUILD__ instead."
```

So, how do I convert uses of `__CUDACC_VER__` into something that will work both for older and newer versions of NVCC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer:

For newer versions at least, the [NVCC documentation](http://lutgw1.lunet.edu/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Compiler_Driver_NVCC.pdf) tells us (on Page 3) what the formula is:

> ```
> __CUDACC_VER__ = 
>      __CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__ * 10000 +
>      __CUDACC_VER_MINOR__ * 100 +
>      __CUDACC_VER_BUILD__
> ```

thus, for example, checking for an nvcc from CUDA 7.5 or later means checking

```
(__CUDACC_VER__ > 70500)
```

and with the triplet of values you would write

```
(__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__ > 7) or ((__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__ == 7) and (__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__ >= 5))
```

instead.